# How can one switch between Homebrew Apache and Node.js on MacOS?

Tags: node.js, macos, apache, homebrew

How can one switch between Homebrew Apache (using [GetGrav's MacOS instructions](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions)) and Node.js development environments?

Using Homebrew Apache, one can develop locally using `VirtualHost` like `http://home.test` (mapping to `~/Sites/home.test/index.html`, for example).

But when one loads a project based on Node.js (ex. `http://localhost:3000`), it overrules Homebrew's Apache configuration (i.e. `home.test` is no longer accessible in the browser).

Is it possible to run both concurrently? If not, is there a way to switch between configurations?

Comment: You have a server (Apache HTTPD) running on port 80 and different one (written using Node.js) on port 3000. They should be **completely** independent. What problem are you having running them at the same time?

Comment: @Quentin, that's what I would think too. But after starting a node environment, my browser ignores the virtualhosts from the homebrew apache environment are ignored (i.e. browser to `home.test` leads to 404, but `localhost:3000` works as expected)

Comment: That *really* isn't normal behaviour.

Comment: @Quentin, you're probably right. I suspect it's a conflict with docker now.